# Can I use the new java 8 time API within a scala Play 2.3.8 project?

Tags: scala, playframework, java-8, java-time

I thought that this was feasible by setting the java version to 1.8 (`java.runtime.version=1.8` inside `system.properties` file). But when I tried to compile the project using `activator compile` I got all kinds of `not found: type LocalDateTime` errors.

Am I doing something wrong (configuration-wise)? Is there any way to overcome this issue or is this a known limitation?

I'm using

- `Play framework: 2.3.8`
- `Scala: 2.11.6`
- `Sbt: 0.13.7`

Comment: What happens if you add `scalacOptions += "-target:jvm-1.8"` to your `build.sbt` ?

Comment: What jdk do you have ?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh open jdk 1.8

Comment: @m-z Adding this option has no effect :(

Comment: Is `$JAVA_HOME` is pointing to your JDK 1.8 installation?

Comment: @SeanVieira You're absolutely right! My `JAVA_HOME` pointed to Java 7. Thanks a lot! You saved my day :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First check your java version: 
in cmd - `java --version` (should pointed on your installed java).

If everything is ok you can "force" play to using java 1.8 by insert in your `build.sbt` below code

```
javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.8", "-target", "1.8")
```

in my projects it's working :)